# Exclude Folder with Laravel File::allFiles

Tags: image, laravel, file, directory

I am currently using the following function:

```
public function recentImages(){
    foreach(\File::allFiles("up") as $path){
        $files[] = pathinfo($path);
    }
    return view('recent-images-view')->with('files',$files);
}
```

To list all images in my upload folder, however this also include the thumbnails that are separated in a separated folder called "thumbs".

I was wondering if there's any way to tell the allFiles function to exclude the folders with the name thumbs. Or should I handle this completely differently?

Thanks for any information in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`File::allFiles()` will get all of the files from the given directory recursively. Try using `File::files()` which will get all files from the given directory only.

**Update**

Since you have other directories which you need. I came up with following solution.

```
public function images(){
    foreach(\File::directories('up') as $dir) { // Get all the directories
        if(str_contains('thumbs', $dir)) { // Ignore thumbs directory
            continue;
        }            

        foreach(\File::files($dir) as $path) { // Get all the files in each directory
            $files[] = pathinfo($path);
        }
    }

    return view('recent-images-view')->with('files',$files);
}
```

Didn't test it, the concept is get all the directories and get all the files inside those directory by ignoring the unwanted directory.

Comment: Thing is I've got one upload folder with many autogenerated subdirectories as based on year/month. So can I make use of files() to then exclude the thumbs folder which is located inside the months folder?

In general the path looks something like this: 

Image file: up\2017\01\07004210-logoflat.jpg
Thumb file: up\2017\01\thumbs\thm_07004210-logoflat.jpg

I'm currently also thinking of a better way to actually solve this as it might be a bit hard on the server to call all the files each time someone requests it. Would uploading this to a database and calling the files from there be good?

Comment: @RafaëlDeJongh Thought of another way. I can't comment on whether uploading to database is a good way, since I don't have experience on that. You can try it out

Comment: Thanks for the follow up reply! Much appreciated, however the current concept code results in an Undefined variable: files error.

I already was thinking of doing it in a way like this, so I'll probably try to base myself on your code and see what I can fix. However at first look I didn't directly managed to fix the issue at hand.

Either way thanks for the assistance!

Edit: It seems to be caused because directories only parses out the first subfolder and not the subfolders of the subfolders sadly enough. (echo output = up\2017)

Comment: Second edit: Having this setup might work for my general file structure:

    foreach(\File::directories("up/".date("Y")) as $dir) {
            if(str_contains("thumbs", $dir)) {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach(\File::files($dir) as $path) {
                    $files[] = pathinfo($path);
                }
        }

Edit: Scrap that, I forgot that file:directories looks for the subfolder in a given folder. so remove the /m from the date fixed it ;)

Well that does it for this question, thanks for the assistance! Much appreciated ;)

Comment: @RafaëlDeJongh Glad I could help you

Comment: Really appreciate it ;) and here's the final code to first check if there is any folder present and if not to create it. To then loop through the year folders located in the first sublevel of the "up" folder. To then loop through all the folders from all the years which are the months and then to return all the files listed in that subdirectory.

Because of the File:files function only listing the files in the current folder we do not require to make the if structure checker for the thumb as that is yet another sub folder which isn't looped through.

Comment: So with that said here's the full code currently used:

`<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use File;
class RecentImagesController extends Controller{
 public function recentImages(){
  $thumbPath = public_path('up/').date("Y/m").'/thumbs/';
  File::isDirectory($thumbPath) or File::makeDirectory($thumbPath,0775,true,true);
  foreach(File::directories("up") as $dirYears){
   foreach(File::directories($dirYears) as $dir){
    foreach(File::files($dir) as $path){
     $files[] = pathinfo($path);
    }
   }
  }
 return view("recent-images-view")->with("files",$files);
 }
}`

Comment: If anyone does know a better way to handle this. Like perhaps save the path location of each upload in a database and then loop through the database most recent entrees. Then feel free to let me know!

The search now is to find a way to sort the listed files with the above loop descending so they actually come up in the list as most recent at the top. While I do know how this is possible via Database and filtering on date/timestamps, I'm currently trying to find out how to handle this with a loop like this (even though each image gets an hour/minute/second stamp before the original name).

Comment: Alright I've managed to get around that by using array_reverse() in the first foreach loop to sort by most recent.

So yea that pretty fixes all the problems and questions for this issue ;)